# Heist movie where a guy uses camouflage and fails

Tags: identify-this-movie

This movie dates to before 2000. It is about a heist, if I recall correctly, a diamond is the objective. The particular scene I remember is one guy using a camouflage to blend with the floor of the place. The pattern used was b&w diamonds. But he is detected and cut in pieces with a laser (not sure about this last part).

I am sure the movie is well known. I have seen it several times when I was a kid.

Additional details:

- I think the robbery was some sort of competence or skill demonstration, rather than a conventional robbery.
- In the scene of the guy with the camouflage clothes, I recall him being watched on a monitor and blending perfectly with the floor. 
  When he is discovered there is a part when he falls from a stair. I think mutilated or something.
- The place looks like a museum rather than a bank.

Additional detail:

- When I watched the movie it gave me the impression the guy was a clown, to be more precise a harlequin. (The movie was not Quick Change)

Comment: Do you remember what kind of movie it was? A thriller, or a comedy? A realistic movie or maybe sci-fi(-ish)?

Comment: I am not sure, I recall it was a thriller, it was not sci-fi but it was not very realistic. let say it displays the same level of realism than the James Bond movies.

Comment: And it's not F/X or F/X 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This movie is [*Shalimar* (1978)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078241/), a Hindi film.

It was also released in the US in English.

I have seen this film and it has the exact same things described above.

The pattern... and the museum look of the place... The person challenges a group gathered to steal the diamond/artifact which is kept in a room full of laser detectors.

Comment: Yes, it is. First I had my doubts because Hindi films are barely known around here but after watching the film I had no doubts it is. The scene mentioned in the question is the last scene that starts at 1:50. Even the English title of the movie "Raiders of the sacred stone" sounds familiar to me. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome.